# How to format text inside Jquery.fs.selecter.js selecter-item (<option>)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selecter-plugin

I know this might not be how a selecter may be used, but

Is there any obvious way to have something like this example:

```
<option value="2">Number of guests <span>4</span></option>
```

Into something like:

**Outcome:**

```
<span class="selecter-item" data-value="4">Number of guests <span>4</span></span>
```

*Note the wrapped number.* That is what I want to achieve, some way to capture a value inside the  or perhaps as a attribute of the  and append that inside *.selecter-item*

One thought was to use JQ to look for each option's "data-value" and add that value too each relevant selecter-item? I'm not sure if that's a nice way to do it though.

Comment: Your initial HTML, with the `span` inside the `option` is invalid. You cannot place HTML within an `option` element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right but where's said like that?

Comment: @C-link: you mean reference?

Comment: @C-link: [(This)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/option.html) says: *"Permitted Contents: Normal character data"*, which in turn means: [(this)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/syntax.html#normal-character-data).

Comment: I know that.  I'm interested in achieving the outcome, it's not invalid to have the number wrapped in a span in the outcome. I only listed it in the example, because I have no clue how to achieve the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. It's probably not the best way to do it, but for my purposes.

My html:

```
<select name="guests-count" id="guests-count">
  <option value="0">4</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
</select>
```

I used this bit of script:

```
$("#guests select").selecter({
  callback: onChange
});

guests = ' <span>Guests</span>';

// Append 'Guests' to the values
$('.selecter-selected').append(guests);
$('.selecter-item').append(guests);
```

which gave me this html:

```
<div class="selecter-options">
  <span class="selecter-item selected first" data-value="0">4 
    <span>Guests</span>
  </span>
  <span class="selecter-item" data-value="4">4 
    <span>Guests</span>
  </span>
  <span class="selecter-item" data-value="8">8 
    <span>Guests</span>
  </span>
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Which is enough hooks to style the number seperatly from the "guests" wording.